# Fill parent div with multiple child divs by adjusting margins

Tags: css, html, css-float, margin

What I have:

A parent div `.parent` which takes the entire window `width=100%` as width but a certain minimum width of, let's say, `min-width=800px`.

Now I have about 20 `.child` divs which, let's say, use a width of `width=300px`, an undefined height, `margin:20px` and `display:inline-block`.

The problem now is that on e.g. smaller screens two divs will be displayed each row but they won't be centered anymore since their neighbour dropped into the next row.

I tried `float:center` and `margin:5px auto 5px auto;` on the children, but float doesn't seem to work at all and the margin just results in 0 margin

So what I want is:

horizontally center all child divs in the parent while still using e.g. 80% of the screen width by adjusting the margins between them. Part 2 is more of an optional thing

How it looks right now (not working of course)

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="host 1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="host 2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="host 3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="host 4">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="host 5">&nbsp;</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.buttons {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:50px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
.host {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:20px 20px 5px 20px;
    height:20px;
    width:300px;
    float:center;
}
```

Comment: could you post some code? ideally just a relevant snippet of css & html. or even better a jsfiddle illustrating the issue. ta!

Comment: Please provide some code, anyway `float:center` doesn't exists, and have you tried `text-align:center` in the container?

Comment: @GionaF well that was fast :D . Make it an answer and I'll accept it, since it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center them horizontally, add `text-align:center;` to the parent:

```
.buttons {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:50px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/rcAQc/)

---

### Equal margins all around

Probably there are hundreds of better ways to do it, but
...that's mine on a saturday lazy afternoon :)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/B6Xec/) (resize the window)

(same html and css as above)

```
var hosts = $('.host');
var buttons= $('.buttons');
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    var w = buttons.width();
    /* how many .host in one row ? */
    var oneRow = Math.floor(w/300);
    /* let's go! */
    if(oneRow>1){
        /* send hosts to the margin calculation function */
        calcMargins(hosts,w,oneRow);
        /* do we have some orphans?! */
        var orphans = hosts.length%oneRow;
        if(orphans!=0){
            /* let's do the same for them */
           var orphansEl = hosts.slice(-orphans);
           calcMargins(orphansEl,w,orphans);
       }
    }else{
        /* there's only one div per row, so
            we reset everything */
        hosts.css({'margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto','float':'none'});
    }
});

/* here's the function */
function calcMargins(els,l,r){
    /* total blank space */
    var tSpace = l - (r*300);
    /* we'll add a right margin for each .host and
         a margin-left for the first of each row */
    var nElements = r + 1; 
    /* it's better to leave some pixels behind
        than cause a line wrap, so we'll floor the division */
   var rightMargin = Math.floor(tSpace/nElements);
   /* finally, we set the margins */
   els.each(function(i){
       if(i%r == 0){
           /* left margin for first .host of each row */
           leftMargin = rightMargin;
       }else{
           /* left margin for the rest */
           leftMargin = 0;
       }
       /* here we go */
       $(this).css({'float':'left','margin-left':leftMargin,'margin-right':rightMargin});
    });
}​
```

Obviously it's written this way for clarity, but you can reduce it to:

```
var hosts = $('.host'), buttons= $('.buttons');
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    var w = buttons.width(), oneRow = Math.floor(w/300);
    if(oneRow>1){
        calcMargins(hosts,w,oneRow);
        var orphans = hosts.length%oneRow;
        if(orphans!=0) calcMargins(hosts.slice(-orphans),w,orphans);
    }else{
        hosts.css({'margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto','float':'none'});
    }
});
function calcMargins(els,l,r){
   var rightMargin = Math.floor((l-(r*300))/(r+1));
   els.each(function(i){
       leftMargin = (i%r == 0) ? rightMargin : 0;
       $(this).css({'float':'left','margin-left':leftMargin,'margin-right':rightMargin});
    });
}​
```

and if you don't want the "orphans" to be centered, here's an even smaller version:

```
var hosts = $('.host'), buttons= $('.buttons');
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    var l = buttons.width(), r = Math.floor(l/300);
    if(r>1){
       var rightMargin = Math.floor((l-(r*300))/(r+1));
       hosts.each(function(i){
           leftMargin = (i%r == 0) ? rightMargin : 0;
           $(this).css({'float':'left','margin-left':leftMargin,'margin-right':rightMargin});
        });
    }else{
        hosts.css({'margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto','float':'none'});
    }
});
```

...that comes with a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/B7tGT/)**.

---

If anyone has a shorter solution, i'ld love to learn it :)

Comment: thanks again. Any idea how to give a `.host` some sort of variable margin to another `.host` , yet not becoming smaller than e.g. `10px` ?

Comment: Mmh there's no `min-`/`max-` `margin` @Wurstbro :( but if you explain me what you want to achieve, i can try to find a workaround.

Comment: If I open your fiddle I have two divs each in the first two  rows, one in the last. What I want to do is make the two divs in row one have the same distance between each other like they have to the window's border.

Comment: Not that easy @Wurstbro :) are you already using jQuery in your project? Maybe i can find a js solution.

Comment: yep. It's not that important tho, don't wanna waste your time ;)

Comment: works nice but now I have the problem that some hosts aren't 20px heigh, ruining your js :/ . I'll try to figure it out or check back here for your answer :)

Comment: I fixed it by adding higher top margin and setting the bottom margin to the minus the div's height. Guess I can't explain that easily here. If you wanna I can PM you the URL so you can check it out *(which is not possbile)

Comment: Ok @Wurstbro , if you want to try it, i've made a quick edit here: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Vjeyz/ to add a clearfix after each row. Anyway, pm me the url (can you PM?! didn't know it!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17650/discussion-between-wurstbro-and-gionaf)

Comment: Somehow .buttons always creates a horizontal scrollbar when there less than 4 elements/row

Comment: clear:both still didnt work in chrome. I just used JS to remove the scrollbar if not needed :D http://jsfiddle.net/vbf3Z/4/ , buttons having a min-width of 800 now

Comment: well since the content rescales above 800px and theyre only hidden above 800 px I really see no problem :)